# Sqlite create table with check constraint

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am adding check constraint in sqlite android using create table query but Getting error like this

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: bloodgrp (code 1): ,

```
  String query =  " CREATE TABLE " + register + " ( " +
                Name + " varchar(200), " +
                Age + " TEXT, " +
                gender + "TEXT, " +
                Email + " TEXT, " +
                Username + " TEXT, "+ "type UNIQUE, " +
                password + " TEXT, " +
                contactNo + "TEXT, " +
                 Address + "TEXT, " +
                 city + "TEXT, " +
                 img + "Blob ," +
                bloodgrp + " TEXT, "+
                 Uid + "TEXT, " +
                 " CHECK " +"("+ bloodgrp ='A+''A-''B+''B-''AB+''AB-''O-''O+"+"))";
```

db.execSQL(query);

Comment: This string does not even compile. Edit your question with your exact code.

Comment: I have query only in check constraint which is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the check constraint as shown below. This answer assumes *register*, *Name*, *Age*, *gender*, *Email*, *Username*, *password*, *contactNo*, *Address*, *city*, *img*, *bloodgrp*, *Uid* are initialized correctly.

> CHECK ( *column_name* in (*value1*, *value2*, *value3*))

```
String query =  " CREATE TABLE " + register + " ( " +
            Name + " varchar(200), " +
            Age + " TEXT, " +
            gender + "TEXT, " +
            Email + " TEXT, " +
            Username + " TEXT, "+ "type UNIQUE, " +
            password + " TEXT, " +
            contactNo + "TEXT, " +
            Address + "TEXT, " +
            city + "TEXT, " +
            img + "Blob ," +
            bloodgrp + " TEXT, "+
            Uid + "TEXT, " +
            " CHECK ("+ bloodgrp +" in ('A+','A-','B+','B-','AB+','AB-','O-','O+')));";
```